# Cant install MS office on Kubuntu

Tags: software-installation, wine, playonlinux

Recently I have tried to install Microsoft Office on Ubuntu with different versions (2010,2013 and 2019), both with 64 and 32 bits attempting to do it with wine and playonlinux, but I have not succeeded on it.

When I try to install it with wine,the setup starts correctly and everything works fine, until the progress bar reaches the end and then it show up this message,with nothing else than it:

```
Microsoft office proffesional plus has detected an error during installation.
```

When I attempt to install it with POL, everything goes fine and I put the setup file in but then this error appears:

```
Error in POL_Wine
Wine parece haber fallado sí el programa está funcionando, ignore este mensaje.
```

What should I do then? Thanks

Comment: Neither `wine` nor PlayOnLinux runs ALL windows programs. Would LibreOffice do what you need?

Comment: Sorry,I need ms office because libreoffice doesnt detect errors,so is urgent.Actuallyi got to install 2007 on play on linux but I need a more recent version

Comment: Did you have a look at the playonlinux page: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-3-0.html ?  They have several installers there.

Comment: It might be easier to install a compatible version of Windows in a virtual machine and use that to run Office (yes, I feel dirty for suggesting it)...